# python: ValueError: x and y must be the same size

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
housing = pd.read_csv("housing.csv")
X = housing[['latitude', 'longitude']].to_numpy()
X
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
housing_median_house_value=housing['median_house_value']
y =housing_median_house_value.ravel()
y
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_validation, y_train, y_validation = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)

from sklearn import linear_model

model1 = linear_model.LinearRegression()

model1.fit(X, y)   
print(model1.intercept_,model1.coef_)

theta0, theta1,thetal2 = model1.intercept_, model1.coef_[0], model1.coef_[1] #train完

print(theta0, theta1,thetal2) 
>>-5829397.044942677 -69550.96552198952 -71209.3691841117

plt.figure(figsize = (12,8))
plt.scatter(X, y)

vx = np.linspace(0,110000,100)
vz = np.linspace(0,110000,100)
print(vx)
print(vz)
vy = theta0 + theta1 * vx + thetal2 * vz
print(vy)
plt.plot(vx, vy, vz, c='r')

ValueError: x and y must be the same size
```

I had already check the vx,vz,vy size, they all are (100,). However, it still can't run. Please help me, thanks!

Comment: Please make sure to include tags for the major libraries you're using when you ask a question.

Comment: It would help to include the full error traceback. You may be trying to fix the error in the wrong place

Comment: The problem is the line `plt.scatter(X, y)` ... `X` is an array with shape `(100, 2)` and `y` is shape `(100,)`. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I use python, and the develop environment is jupyter.

Comment: I want to use plot the linear regression. I'm looking for the housing near (35.612, -117.686). And find how much is expected to buy a house.@Chris A

Comment: remove the line `plt.scatter(X, y)` - it's what is throwing the error

Comment: It can run, but it can not show the scatter points. Only the line. I want to plot the scatter and line.

Comment: Look into [`seaborn.regplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html)

Comment: I want to plot the X and y scatter point, and the line is the scatter's predict.@Chris A

Comment: I think the problem is what you said the X.shape is (20640, 2), and the y.shape is (20640,), but I need the latitude and longitude to as the X, do you know how can I achieve.@Chris A